# Regarding converting Date formats

Tags: r, date

I need to convert "dates" column  into date format, but i am getting NA values 
any suggestions please

```
str(dli)
'data.frame':   39474 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Regions: chr  "Tiruchengode" "Tiruchengode" "Tiruchengode" "Tiruchengode" ...
 $ Item   : chr  "TRACTOR TT35-4WD" "TRACTOR TT35-4WD" "TRACTOR TT35-4WD" "TRACTOR TT35-4WD" ...
 $ Dates  : chr  "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04" ...
 $ Data   : int  2 7 6 0 6 6 1 6 0 4 ...
```

### My actual data is as follows

```
trac <- as.Date(dli$Dates, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

I am using  the above command to execute my output

My output is

```
trac <- as.Date(dli$Dates, "%d/%m/%Y")

trac
   [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [30] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [59] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [88] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [117] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [146] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [175] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: The 'Dates' are in a different format and seems to be in the `"%Y-%m-%d"` format which is the default format of `as.Date` You just need `as.Date(dli$Dates)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates are already in the `Date` format i.e. `%Y-%m-%d`.  So, we just need to apply `as.Date` (posting from the earlier posted comments)

```
as.Date(dli$Dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function you use to convert the character to date, you are specifying a date format that does not correspond to the date format of your date format.

On the dummy `data.frame`

```
dli <- data.frame(Dates = c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", 
                            "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04"))
```

Changing the format to `"%Y-%m-%d"` returns:

```
trac <- as.Date(dli$Dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
trac
[1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04"
```

A second alternative would be using `lubridate` which makes working with dates more easy:

```
library(lubridate)
```

You can use the function `ymd()` (i.e. year month day) to convert your date. It will infer the format automatically.

```
trac <- ymd(dli$Dates)
trac
[1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04"
```